# Docker build takes long time for nodejs application

Tags: node.js, docker

I am experiencing long build times for nodejs applications when building image with docker build command.

There is one big hang that takes couple of minutes

```
08:03:15  Step 1/11 : FROM node:14.1.0-alpine AS build
08:03:15   ---> 0854fcfc1637
08:03:15  Step 2/11 : COPY server/package*.json /nodejs/server/
08:03:15   ---> Using cache
08:03:15   ---> 4996283ff991
08:03:15  Step 3/11 : WORKDIR /nodejs/server
08:03:15   ---> Using cache
08:03:15   ---> 93e5b63fa81d
08:03:15  Step 4/11 : RUN npm ci
08:03:15   ---> Using cache
08:03:15   ---> 2c825e02ea01
08:03:15  Step 5/11 : COPY server ./
08:03:15   ---> Using cache
08:03:15   ---> 69c024cde79f
08:03:15  Step 6/11 : WORKDIR /nodejs
08:03:15   ---> Using cache
08:03:15   ---> 49d7f8bd9514
08:03:15  Step 7/11 : COPY package*.json ./
08:03:16   ---> e82bee625c3e
08:03:16  Step 8/11 : RUN npm ci
08:03:16   ---> Running in ecfd57702906
...
08:03:49  added 1483 packages in 26.419s
08:09:40  Removing intermediate container ecfd57702906
...
08:09:40   ---> 7c6b67d85b0b
08:09:40  Step 9/11 : COPY *.json ./
08:09:43   ---> 0165efd1c97d
08:09:43  Step 10/11 : COPY src ./src/
08:09:51   ---> 42e54cee6b91
08:09:51  Step 11/11 : RUN npm run build:prod
08:09:51   ---> Running in af6f9b013d27
```

This does not happen when building Java images.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.1.0-alpine AS build
COPY server/package*.json /nodejs/server/
WORKDIR /nodejs/server
RUN npm ci
COPY server ./

WORKDIR /nodejs
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY *.json ./
COPY src ./src/
RUN npm run build:prod
...
```

I tried using buildkit but it has the same behaviour

```
08:37:20  #17 exporting to image
08:37:20  #17 exporting layers
08:50:12  #17 exporting layers 766.8s done
```

I also added node_modules to .dockerignore file but with no change.

Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c

What could be the problem?

What is happening between "added 1483 packages..." and "Removing intermediate container"?

Comment: Do you see `Step 11/11 : RUN npm run build:prod`? In that case, try removing that row and run again, after step 10/10, run `docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/sh` too ssh to the container. Then try running `npm run build:prod` directly in the terminal window to see the result. My guess is that that the server might be crashing when trying to start.

Comment: Yes I can see it (just added to my question) but it is executed after the hang. It might be hard to try your suggestion because the machine is a Jenkins agent but I will try to do it.

Comment: Ah i see, yes that it's not an issue with that command. Try the same thing but remove the last 4 lines then and run `npm ci` manually on the container, see if the installation of packages breaks. Since you're using alpine, it has a lot of missing packages which might be needed. I had the same issue a few weeks ago. Also, if you're installing many and heavy packages which needs building and make etc you have to make sure that your docker have enough resources. Open docker app -> resources and allocate some more CPU, RAM & Swap if possible to speed up things (Just don't allocate all).

Comment: Thanks @JonathanNielsen I tried your suggestion but build behaves normally when run from inside of container. Also docker stats shows that container has limit of 6GB RAM so this also does not look like a problem. one thing I have noticed is that during npm ci Google asks for allowing analytics so I added ENV NG_CLI_ANALYTICS false in Dockerfile, but still the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the cause of the problem and wanted to share if someone encounters similar issue.

The long "export layers" time was caused by node_modules folder that was present in one of the layers. Removing it solved the problem but it's really a workaround.

I merged npm ci and npm run build... steps together and removed node_modules in the same step.

```
RUN npm ci && npm run build:prod && rm -rf node_modules
```

So the final build stage in Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM node:14.1.0-alpine AS build
COPY server/package*.json /nodejs/server/
WORKDIR /nodejs/server
RUN npm ci
COPY server ./

WORKDIR /nodejs
COPY package*.json ./
COPY *.json ./
COPY src ./src/
RUN npm ci && npm run build:prod && rm -rf node_modules
...
```

As I said it's just a workaround and I think the root cause is that Docker is having problems with exporting layers with a lot of small files such as the ones in node_modules.